# Mixing typed matches with sequence matcher gives out strange behaviour in Scala

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm trying to figure out what's going on on this piece of code, trying to figure out if there is something I don't understand or if it is a compiler bug or unintuitive spec, let's define these two almost identical functions:

```
def typeErause1(a: Any) = a match {
    case x: List[String] => "stringlists"
    case _ => "uh?"
}
def typeErause2(a: Any) = a match {
    case List(_, _) => "2lists"
    case x: List[String] => "stringlists"
    case _ => "uh?"
}
```

now if I call `typeErause1(List(2,5,6))` I get `"stringlists"` because even if it is actually `List[Int]` with type erasure it is not able to tell the difference. But strangely if I call `typeErause2(List(2,5,6))` I get `"uh?"` and I don't understand why it is not matching `List[String]` like it did before. If I use `List[_]` instead on the second function it is able to match it correctly which makes me think this is a bug in scalac.

I'm using Scala 2.9.1

Comment: It's a bug in the matcher -- there are plenty tickets about it, and it should work starting with Scala 2.10.x.

Comment: do you have a link to the ticket so I can choose you as the answer?

Comment: As I said, there are plenty tickets about the matcher, and I'm really not particularly interested in hunting for the one that covers this particular case.

Comment: well thanks for your opinion but I was looking for a sustained reason and "it's a bug in the matcher because there are plenty of tickets about the matcher" is not one.

Comment: I'm not "opining" here, and you have as much access to the ticket list as I am. Stack Overflow is not "let others do the look up for me".

Comment: @ilcavero - Daniel didn't answer; he left a comment. You're welcome to wait for someone to answer with supporting links, or look it up and answer yourself. Rudeness, however, [is not welcome](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bug in the matcher ;) The pattern matcher is being (has been?) [rewritten](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533826/what-is-scalas-experimental-virtual-pattern-matcher) for 2.10

I just checked with the latest nightly and your code works as expected:

```
Welcome to Scala version 2.10.0-20120426-131046-b1aaf74775 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_31).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> def typeErause1(a: Any) = a match {
     |     case x: List[String] => "stringlists"
     |     case _ => "uh?"
     | }
warning: there were 2 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
typeErause1: (a: Any)String

scala> def typeErause2(a: Any) = a match {
     |     case List(_, _) => "2lists"
     |     case x: List[String] => "stringlists"
     |     case _ => "uh?"
     | }
warning: there were 3 unchecked warnings; re-run with -unchecked for details
typeErause2: (a: Any)String

scala> typeErause1(List(2,5,6))
res0: String = stringlists

scala> typeErause2(List(2,5,6)) 
res1: String = stringlists
```