# What exactly did Scala improve with pattern matching in 2.10?

Tags: scala, scala-2.10

I found it interesting that [this puzzler](http://scalapuzzlers.com/index.html#pzzlr-002), specifically this code:

```
val (i, j): (Int, Int) = ("3", "4")
```

Fails at runtime in Scala 2.9.1, but fails at compile time w/ 2.10 M3(which is great).  I try to track what's coming in new Scala releases, but I'm unable to connect the dots here.  What improvement led to this more precise behavior?

Comment: I have no idea why that would fail at runtime and not compile time in any version of Scala.

Comment: I guess that it just slipped through a test somewhere. It's actually kind of funny: I was talking to a Python devotee yesterday about how great Scala is, only to find today that Scala fails when presented with an assignment that's almost classic Python in nature.

Comment: `val (i:Int, j:Int) = ("3","4")` fails at compile-time in 2.9.1

Comment: @pmcs - Scala *is* great! But nothing is perfect ;)

Comment: @Dan - assignment in scala is done as follows: `val p = x` where `p` is any pattern. The pattern `x: (Int, Int)` is a runtime type check, but remember at runtime, due to **type erasure**, the type `(Int, Int)` is really just `Tuple2`. This is why it compiles but falls over with a class cast exception at runtime

Comment: @pmcs The closest Scala equivalent to python is: `val (i,j) = ("3","4")`. It just works. And as in python you will need to convert the strings in ints if you need arithmetic.

Comment: @pmcs You realize that the whole point of the example is that it _should_ fail, right? If Python accepts it, then it's doing worse than both Scala 2.9.1 (fails at runtime) and Scala 2.10 (fails at compile time). But I suppose it would fail in Python as well, as soon as you try to use `i` or `j` as numbers.

Comment: @oxbow_lakes Why is that pattern a *runtime* check unlike ML, OCaml, F#, Haskell etc.? For example, `let (a, b) : int * int = "3", "4"` gives a type error in OCaml or F#.

Comment: @JonHarrop: interesting point; I guess it's a consequence of allowing arbitrary pattern matching. For instance, val Foo((a, b): (Int, Int)) = ("3", "4") can be valid, for instance if Foo.unapply has type Any => Option[Any]. In that case, the typecheck _must_ be done at run-time. I don't think you can express this without subtyping, and none of the languages you mention has user-defined extractors AFAIK.
Still, in some cases the typecheck can be proven earlier to fail, so currently Scala is just as good in this example.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The thing that's going on is that the new pattern matcher is much easier to enhance and maintain, because it's not a rats nest piece of code. The following example code should also exhibit the same change:

```
("3", "4") match { case (i, j): (Int, Int) => /* whatever */ }
```

What's happening is Scala understanding at compile time that the pattern can never be matched.

Answer (score 16):

In scala 2.10, the pattern matcher has had a complete re-write and is now the *virtualized pattern matcher*. [**Read more about it!**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533826/what-is-scalas-experimental-virtual-pattern-matcher)

Comment: Well, the virtual part is just internal unless you pass a flag, iirc. The actual output is not virtual (ie, is not implemented as calls on a monad).

Comment: Well, yes. But the main point is that it represents a complete re-write (which would explain why its behaviour may have changed)

Comment: Why should the pattern matcher make any difference to this example? I would expect the compiler to reject the code during type checking before it ever got to the pattern matcher...