# Factoring out common cases in pattern matching with partial function

Tags: scala, functional-programming, partial-functions

I routinely use partial functions to factor out common clauses in exception handling. For example:

```
val commonHandler: PartialFunction[Throwable, String] = {
  case ex: InvalidClassException => "ice"
}

val tried = try {
  throw new Exception("boo")
}
catch commonHandler orElse {
  case _:Throwable => "water"
}

println(tried) // water
```

Naturally, I expected that the `match` keyword also expects a partial function and that I should be able to do something like this:

```
  val commonMatcher: PartialFunction[Option[_], Boolean] = {
    case Some(_) => true
    case None => false
  }

  Some(8) match commonMatcher // Compilation error
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `match` is a keyword, not a method, and its syntax does not accept a partial function on its right side (see below). There however exists a `pipe` method (since 2.13), which, same as `map` or `foreach`, accepts a partial function. You can therefore write:

```scala
import scala.util.chaining._

Some(8).pipe(commonMatcher)
```

There was some discussion regarding this (see [Pre SIP: Demote match keyword to a method](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/pre-sip-demote-match-keyword-to-a-method/2137/40)) and there was a PR which made possible to use the `match` a bit more like a method ([Change match syntax #7610](https://github.com/lampepfl/dotty/pull/7610)), with a dot, but still the syntax is the `match` keyword needs to be followed by case clauses, see https://docs.scala-lang.org/scala3/reference/syntax.html:

```
InfixExpr         ::=  ... other variants ommitted here ...
                    |  InfixExpr MatchClause

SimpleExpr        ::=  ... other variants ommitted here ...
                    |  SimpleExpr ‘.’ MatchClause

MatchClause       ::=  ‘match’ <<< CaseClauses >>>

CaseClauses       ::=  CaseClause { CaseClause }
CaseClause        ::=  ‘case’ Pattern [Guard] ‘=>’ Block
```

Compare this with `catch` syntax:

```
Expr1             ::=  ... other variants ommitted here ...
                    |  ‘try’ Expr Catches [‘finally’ Expr]

Catches           ::=  ‘catch’ (Expr | ExprCaseClause)
```

Comment: Regarding making `match` a method see also (outdated) Scala-virtualized https://github.com/TiarkRompf/scala-virtualized https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533826/what-is-scalas-experimental-virtual-pattern-matcher